# Choosing database and licensing for Delphi application

Tags: database, delphi, firebird, embedded-database, firebird-embedded

We have Delphi XE2. We are looking for a database for our application. We have tried Absolute Database and it supports most of SQL commands we need. I see most of Delphi users choose Firebird but it seems to hard to work with. I am so much confused about databases and licenses. Here are my problems:

1. When we choose a database, let's say Absolute Database, Firebird, MySql embedded etc. and if we have for example 3.000 customers, do we still need to pay to Database developers? Or is it one time fee? I am so much confused because they say when we buy, we can use it inside our building ( http://www.componentace.com/order/licenses.php ). But when we release our software, our customers will need to use the same database of course.
2. Absolute DB is easy to install and supports most of SQL queries. Firebird does not support most of SQL queries. Is this correct?
3. When we try to use Firebird, we use FlameRobin to design database. But when we try to connect using IB components, it says "Unable to connect database".

Thank you very much...

Comment: For Interbase/Firebird I like IBExpress for admin

Comment: If you work with firebird, I recommend using a comercial programm, like sqlmaestro.com or sqlmanager.net!

Comment: I suggest to you read more about Firebird. Check the "Get to know Firebird in two minutes" paper at http://www.firebirdnews.org/?page_id=165

Comment: I believe firebird is not as easy as absolute db. am i right?

Comment: Licenses depends on database, and there are different licensing within the same database. For example you can buy "user" or "processor" license, with the former you need a license for each user using the database, with the latter usually you have unlimited user but have to pay (usually a lot...) for each processor (or core) used by the database engine. You have to check with the selected database vendor. Embedded database may requires a license for each user.

Comment: I think that [SQL Lite](http://www.sqlite.org/) is the most popular embedded database, probably because it is free and open source. Even iOS comes with support for SQL Lite built in.

Comment: '[Royalty-free distribution](http://www.componentace.com/bde_replacement_database_delphi_absolute_database.htm)' sounds like there are no costs for installations on end-user systems, only for developer seats.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. It depends on database. Absolute Database is embedded database, everything is included in your exe. Most database engines however are standalone, so they are installed as applications. It looks like if you buy commercial Absolute Database licence, no royalties are needed: http://www.componentace.com/order/order_product.php?id=8
2. Firebird supports most SQL standards. According to this answer, most SQL compliant embedded database is Firebird: [Which embedded database has maximum SQL compliance, and concurrency support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438817/which-embedded-database-has-maximum-sql-compliance-and-concurrency-support)
3. You must have some configuration issues with IB components, hard to say more without more information. On the otherhand, IB components are for Interbase, so you might find something else better, like UIB.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the information. So when we buy this DB, all of our customers can download and use our software and we do not have to pay fee to them? We are planning to buy Single developer license with source code.

Comment: I'm not ComponentAce saleman, but yes. However you say "we", so you need more licences since it's per developer.

Comment: '[Royalty-free distribution](http://www.componentace.com/bde_replacement_database_delphi_absolute_database.htm)' sounds like there are no costs for installations on end-user systems, only for developer seats

Answer (score 11):

1. Firebird has no licensing fees at all. However, it's smart to help maintain this great project once you rely on it. There is a lot of ways to help Firebird project:

   http://www.firebirdsql.org/#consider-your-contribution
2. Not correct. Firebird is very powerful and supports most SQL standards plus a great SQL extensions for stored procedures and triggers
3. Check your database connection string. It's usually something like `server_ip:full_db_path` if you're connecting over a network, or just `full_db_path` if local. You can always use an ALIAS in place of `full_db_path`. Make sure you have Firebird server running or, if using embedded, if it's installed correctly. Firebird has a great and very complete documentation and one of the best support groups on open source projects.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't want to use Firebird Server but embedded. So can you help me how i can set it up? Because i am always getting error on Delphi at desing time. Do I need to distribute files for embedded fb?

Comment: You need to describe what you have done and what kind of errors you get. Maybe create a new question for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you'll choose Firebird, then take a look at [IBExpert](http://www.ibexpert.net/ibe/index.php?n=Main.IBExpertFeatures). This is absolutely the best administration tool available for Firebird. But not cheap. =(

Answer (score 0):

You should also look at Interbase, also marketed by Embarcadero, the Delphi vendor. Interbase is not the same thing as Firebird, which is probably why the IB components you mentioned didn't work.

Yes, each customer will usually have to purchase the IB database. However, there are additional choices with Interbase, depending on how you structure your application. Check how they work and see if they can fit better with what you are trying to do.